# window.open and adding multiple maps to DOM of new window

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, dojo

I have created an HTML template to open from my existing arcgis JavaScript application. The HTML template is to be populated with several maps and text based on a user selection of the main app. My question is, what is the best way to go about copying the same graphics and basemaps from the main application to the new window? My current code adds a new map and I am able to add the basemap as a layer, but it is removed in the main application. I also have not been able to add the graphic layer, although i get no errors when I add to the maps of the new windows.

here is my current code:

```
  var center_left = (screen.width / 2) - (1100 / 2);
  var center_top = (screen.height / 2) - (600 / 2);
  var adminWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=1100,height=600,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,left=' + center_left + ',top=' + center_top);
  var adminDoc = adminWindow.document;
  var adminBody = adminDoc.body;
  adminDoc.write(adminReportTemplate);
  adminDoc.close();

  var parcelTable = this.getParcelTable(); 
  adminDoc.getElementById('parcelTable').innerHTML = parcelTable;

  var parcelExtent = this.results.features[0].geometry.getExtent();

  var basemapLayer = this.map.getLayer(this.map.layerIds[0]);

  var parcelGraphic = this.map.getLayer(this.map.graphicsLayerIds[8]);

  var parcelMap = new Map(adminDoc.getElementById('parcelMap'), {
    extent: parcelExtent,
    basemap:basemapLayer  // Error: Map.setBasemap: Unable to add basemap: "".
  });
  parcelMap.addLayer(basemapLayer); //works but removes basemap from this.map
  parcelMap.graphics.add(parcelGraphic); //no graphics visible, no error
```

Comment: Have you tried `parcelMap.addLayer(parcelGraphic)`? `parcelGraphic` should be a GraphicsLayer object.

Comment: i did try that but now just realized there seems to be a bigger problem. I can get the graphic to show, but only after I zoom in and out a few times. I am also unable to pan around with a mouse click. Seems to be an issue with the map controls in the new window. Also not sure why the graphic doesn't show up right away?

Comment: if i zoom out twice with the (-) button, then zoom in with the mouse wheel, the graphic shows

Comment: also, as stated before, the basemap layer gets added to the new window but removed from the old one